# Advanced search with one tag and any non-tag condition

Tags: support, design

I just found this out today, and I've tested a few different scenarios (likely not exhaustive), but I found it weird that when searching with exactly one tag and at least one non-tag condition (if I can call it like that), the usage guidance part of the tag gets duplicated:

[image]

I checked it on [Super User](https://superuser.com) and [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com) and the same thing doesn't happen there.

It was tested on the Windows version of Google Chrome (68.0.3440.75) and Internet Explorer (11) browsers.

Also generating same weirdness:

- [tag] test
- [tag] user:XXXXX
- score:X [tag]

Comment: How it looks on [superuser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ce2EM.png) for example.

Comment: ow could find the other question, yep, a duplicate